# Is there a SynchronousFuture equivalent of `async`

Tags: flutter, dart

For some reason the compiler is complaining about this:

```
  SynchronousFuture<void> setNewRoutePath(AppLink newLink) {
    _currentLink = newLink;
    // return null; // compiler really wants to see this null return...why?
  }
```

But is happy with this:

```
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(AppLink newLink) async {
    _currentLink = newLink;
  }
```

Seems like `async` keyword is handling the implicit return here. Is there some equivalent for `SynchronousFuture`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```dart
>   SynchronousFuture<void> setNewRoutePath(AppLink newLink) {
>   _currentLink = newLink;
>   // return null; // compiler really wants to see this null return...why?
> }
> ```

You need a return value because your function is declared to return a non-`void` value, so it must return *something*.  You could argue that all functions could implicitly return `null` if there's no explicit `return` statement, but that would be error-prone:

```dart
int f(String someValue) {
  if (someCondition) {
    return 42;
  }
} // f didn't return anything if someCondition is false. Accidental or intentional?
```

`Future`s themselves aren't really special.  If you have a non-`async` function that returns a `Future`, you must still have an explicit `return` statement:

```dart
Future<void> f() {
  print('Hello world!');
} // Error: f doesn't end with a return statement.
```

However, the `async` keyword does a few things:

- Primarily it enables the use of the `await` keyword.
- It automatically wraps returned values in a `Future`.  This includes implicit return values from `void` functions.

`SynchronousFuture` is just an ordinary class provided by Flutter that implements the `Future` interface.  It is not special.  It's not part of the Dart language, so there is not going to be any keyword that does automatic return value wrapping like what the `async` keyword does.

Also note that in your function that returns a `SynchronousFuture`, you should *not* just sprinkle `return null` statements.  With an `async` function, a `return;` statement (or exiting the function without an explicit `return` statement) ultimately returns a `Future<void>()` to the caller.  Callers expect to be able to call methods (e.g. `.then()`) on the returned `Future` to add completion callbacks.  If you return `null` for a `SynchronousFuture`, calling `.then()` on it will result in a null pointer exception at runtime.  You instead would need to use `return SynchronousFuture<void>(null);`.

I also should point out that the [`SynchronousFuture` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/SynchronousFuture-class.html) states:

> In general use of this class should be avoided as it is very difficult to debug such bimodal behavior.

so unless you have some clear need to use a `SynchronousFuture`, you're better off avoiding it.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Indeed `return SynchronousFuture<void>(null);` is what is recommended as I've since discovered.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have created a class called `SynchronousFuture` the compiler will complain as there is no class called `SynchronousFuture` in the dart standard library, so either you or a library you import must define this class.

In `dart` all `async` functions must have a return value of type `Future<T>`.

> // return null; // compiler really wants to see this null
> return...why?

Because `Future` is not the same as `void`, when you return a value in an async function, that value is subsequently used as value for the future, as future is a generic class.

Comment: Ah, perhaps this is a Flutter issue: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/SynchronousFuture-class.html

Comment: Interesting, can you provide more context to your problem, you're right this is something to do with that flutter class, there are some callouts there too about this being difficult to debug.

Comment: The context is just that I have to override some Future<T> method from the flutter SDK (RouterDelegate.setNewRoutPath), and in the docs it says "Consider using a [SynchronousFuture] if the result can be computed"

So I'm just trying to do that... but then it starts asking for this ugly null return.

Comment: If you just need the value to be returned and you don't need to consider the event loop, can you instead use `Future.value()`?

Comment: Like not use the SyncFuture at all? I don't actually have anything to return here(void is return type), and I don't care about the 1frame delay either, so it's not so much a real problem, as just a curious situation. Trying to do what the docs suggest, and running into this odd behavior...